# Fibonacci sequence while loop

Tags: c, fibonacci

I have to write code that displays the Fibonacci sequence to the user desired number of terms and must also use a while loop. I'm not sure why this code isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void) {
    int max;
    printf("Enter the max term of the Fibonacci Sequence:\n");
    scanf("%i", &max);
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    a=2;

    while(a<max) {
        if((a==0||a==1))
        {
            printf("%i\n", &a);
            ++a;
        }
        else if(a>1)
        {
            a=(a-1)+(a-2);
            printf("%i\n", &a);
            ++a;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems to be wrong.

Comment: In your `printf` statements, you are passing a pointer rather than an `int`.  Get rid of the `&` operators, e.g. `printf("%i\n", a);`

Comment: You need to use both `a` and `b` to make this work.  You can't just double `a` and subtract 2 to get the next number.

Comment: That is not the correct algorithm to find the Fibonacci sequence, look up the algorithm for doing so and rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void) {
   int max;
   printf("Enter the max term of the Fibonacci Sequence:\n");
   scanf("%i", &max);
   int n=0;
   int a=0;
   int b=1;
   int next;

   while(n<max) {
      if ( n <= 1 )
        {
          next = n;
          n++;
        }
      else
        {
          next = a + b;
          a = b;
          b = next;
          n++;
        }
      printf("%d\n", next);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

issues with your code:

1. following declaration & initialisation, you set `a=2` => it won't take the *true branch* of the `if` statement  -- `'0'` will not be printed in your result.
2. `a=(a-1)+(a-2);` i.e  `a = 1`
   then you are doing `++a;`  =>  `a == 2`. thus it again `else` statement with same `a==2`.

hence it will print the same value and loop executes infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

In the very beginning of your program (before the `while` loop) `a` is 2 (see the line `a=2`).

And in the `while` loop you do following:

```
a=(a-1)+(a-2); // a = 2-1+2-2 i.e. a = 1
```

and right after it

```
++a; // a == 2
```

So, after it `a==2` again. This loop never ends.

But it is technical problem. More important is that you are trying to calculate not Fibonacci Sequence. In the Fibonacci Sequence each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two. But in your code there is adding of not two previous numbers of Fibonacci Sequence, but previous two Natural numbers.

You have variable `b`, because someone told you to add it. And it was right! Just remember previous found element of the Fibonacci Sequence in `b`. When you know previous one element and current one, it is possible to calculate next one.