# Fibonacci Sequence :something wrong in my codes the results output?

Tags: c, do-while, fibonacci, stdio

the first input is 5 and second input 13 and the output suppose to be 5, 8 ,13

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int lim_up, lim_low, A=5, B=13, C=8;

    printf("\n\n\t ENTER THE LOWER LIMIT: ");
    scanf("%d", &lim_low);
    printf("\n\n\t ENTER THE UPPER LIMIT: ");
    scanf("%d", &lim_up);
    printf("\n\n\t FIBONACCI NUMBERS ARE: ");


    do{
         lim_up++;

         printf("\n\n\t\t\t%d", A);
         A = C+B;
         B = c;
         C= A;
    }while(A<lim_up);
    getch();
}
```

i expect the output to be `5 8 13`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fibonacci sequence while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401864/fibonacci-sequence-while-loop)

Comment: no, i'm using DO-WHILE LOOP @klutt

Comment: `A = A; B = B; C= C;` is a no-op and doesn't do anything

Comment: @laura They are pretty much the same thing.

Comment: The seeds of the sequence are 0 and 1, not 13 and 8.

Comment: `B` is 13 and `C` is 8, and you expect `B + C` to be 8?

Answer (score 2):

The following code print the *Fibonacci* sequence in the interval *[lim_low...lim_up]*:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int lim_up, lim_low;
    printf("ENTER THE LOWER LIMIT: ");
    scanf("%u", &lim_low);
    printf("ENTER THE UPPER LIMIT: ");
    scanf("%u", &lim_up);
    printf("FIBONACCI NUMBERS ARE: ");

    unsigned int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0;

    while(nextTerm <= lim_up){
        if (nextTerm >= lim_low)
            printf("%u ",  nextTerm);

        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We have to calculate all the *Fibonacci* series and when we reach the interval we are interested it we start printing results out.

**Note** : This is not the most efficient way you can do it.
 There is **O(1)** [mathematical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence) that can do it right away without the loop.

**APPENDIX: Doing it the mathematical way**
Here is the code to calculate *F(n)* directly:

```
unsigned fib(unsigned int n) { 
  double phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2; 
  return round(pow(phi, n) / sqrt(5)); 
}
```

Now to get the *n* from *F(n)* you will need the following code:

```
unsigned reverseFib(unsigned int fn) { 
  double phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2; 
  return round(log(sqrt(5) * fn) / log(phi)); 
}
```

**Please Note :**

1. The function above will work for all Fibonacci numbers expect *fn = 1*.
   Why its not working for *fn = 1*? Because *fn = 1* can be revered to give 1 or 2, which will make it impossible to know *n* since there is two possibilities (Mathematically: *F(n)* is not **[bijective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)** for *n* in [1, 2]).
2. Floating point error can *theoretically* occur because our computers don't have infinite precision but this should happen rarely.
3. I tested this function for the first 12 Fibonacci numbers and it did
   work fine, with the exception to *fn = 2* as explained above in
   point **1**.

Comment: Now your answer is the same as mine. :) We both generate `1,0,1,1,2,3,5,...` and skip the first

Comment: Yes, we can, I edited my answer to have more information regarding your question hope it helps:)

Comment: Neat. This means one could use `nextTerm = lim_low; t2 = fib(reverseFib(nextTerm)-1);` to start at an arbitrary location rather than 0,1. Once you find the start, you can continue using `nextTerm = t1 + t2;` as that's more efficient than calling `fib`. This is obviously beyond the scope of the OP's assignment, but thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment and I'm glad I helped. its all thanks to the magic of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci starts with two numbers.

```
unsigned previous = 0;
unsigned current  = 1;
```

The next term is given by the sum.

```
unsigned next = previous + current;
```

Then we can shift everything.

```
previous = current;
current  = next;
```

Now, you just have to introduce a loop, and a check to see whether you should print or exit the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* **********

Fibonacci:
  F[0] = 0
  F[1] = 1
  F[n] = F[n-2] + F[n-1]

********** */

int main(void) {
   unsigned min = 5;
   unsigned max = 13;

   unsigned previous = 0;
   if (previous >= min)
      print("%u\n", current);

   unsigned current = 1;
   while (current <= max) {
      if (current >= min)
         printf("%u\n", current);

      unsigned next = previous + current;
      previous = current;
      current  = next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But there's a simpler solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* **********

Fibonacci:
  F[0] = 0
  F[1] = 1
  F[n] = F[n-2] + F[n-1]

If we don't print the first element, this is the same as
  F[0] = 1
  F[1] = 0
  F[n] = F[n-2] + F[n-1]

Taking this approach simplifies the code. 

********** */

int main(void) {
   unsigned min = 5;
   unsigned max = 13;

   unsigned previous = 1;
   unsigned current  = 0;
   while (current <= max) {
      if (current >= min)
         printf("%u\n", current);

      unsigned next = previous + current;
      previous = current;
      current  = next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Finally, an optimized solution, using the functions provided by @Omarito.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const double phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;

unsigned fib(unsigned n) {
   return round(pow(phi, n) / sqrt(5));
}

unsigned reverse_fib(unsigned fn) {
   return round(log(sqrt(5) * fn) / log(phi));
}

int main(void) {
   unsigned min = 5;
   unsigned max = 13;

   unsigned previous;
   unsigned current;
   if (min == 0) {
      previous = 1;
      current  = 0;
   }
   else if (min == 1) {
      previous = 0;
      current  = 1;
   }
   else {
      current  = min;
      previous = fib(reverse_fib(current)-1);
   }

   while (current <= max) {
      printf("%u\n", current);

      unsigned next = previous + current;
      previous = current;
      current  = next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned next = previous + current;
      previous = current;
      current  = next;` can be replaced with `previous = ( current += previous ) - previous;`. That might be more efficient?

Comment: No, don't do this. This instruction contains **two** assignments and is difficult to read. It makes readers think that you don't trust the compiler to optimize well. But source code should show your **intentions**. The cases when you have to convince a compiler to generate faster and/or smaller code are near to never.

Comment: Readability is usually key, but sometimes optimization takes precedence. The main loop of number crunching can be one of those. Accompanying comments to explain the code would be key. /// And you're wrong about this change showing a lack of trust in the compiler. Quite the opposite, it demonstrates that I trust the compiler not to perform changes that are technically not equivalent (in the event of an overflow).

Comment: Both variants you show are supposed to generate the same machine code, aren't they? Where do you see a difference, especially in case of an overflow?

Comment: @the busybee, `p=c;` can't overflow, but `p=p+c-p;` can. Maybe that's not relevant?

Comment: I don't think that it makes a difference. 1) Let's assume that `p=p+c-p;` will overflow on the addition. But then `n=p+c;` will also overflow. If the overflow throws an exception, both variants will do this at the very same point, *before the assignment*. 2) If overflow (and underflow on the subtraction) don't throw exceptions the results are equal, too. /// Another thought: We are discussing here example source code for a beginner. There is no need for optimization at all, so why make it more complicated? /// No offend, have a nice day!